# Javascript popup div won´t close in IE9

Tags: javascript, css

So in chrome I can open and close the pop-up div using this javascript code:

```
<script language="javascript">
function expand_day(daynr) {
var controlnaam = 'cal_' + daynr;
var control = document.getElementById(controlnaam)
if (control) {
    var pd = document.getElementById('popupDiv');
    if (pd){
        var output = '<table border="0" cellpadding="10" style="width:100%;border:solid 0px #000000;background-color:white;color:black;">';
        output += '<tr><td><span style="float:right;"><a href="Javascript:closePopup();return false;">close</a></span></td></tr>';
        output += '<tr><td>';            
        //alert(control.innerHTML);
        pd.innerHTML = output + control.innerHTML + '</td></tr></table>';
        pd.style.display='block';

    }            
}
}
 function closePopup() {
var pd = document.getElementById('popupDiv');
if (pd){
    pd.style.display='none';
}    
}

</script>
```

But when I do this in Internet Explorer 9 I can open the pop-up div, but can´t close it.
How can I close this in Internet Explorer 9?

Comment: Errors? how are you calling it?

Comment: `<a href="Javascript:closePopup();` to `<a href="javascript:closePopup();` with a lower case `j`

Comment: Lowercase j is not working.. when i put an alert between if (pd){
(alert here)
    pd.style.display='none';
It displays the alert in chrome but in ie9 it is not being displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
<a href="Javascript:closePopup();return false;">close</a>
```

should be changed to

```
<a href="Javascript:closePopup();">close</a>
```

So you can't use `return` statement in this context. IE complains `SCRIPT1018: 'return' statement outside of function`.

http://jsfiddle.net/LMqKg/2/

Аlternatively you could use `onclick` instead of `href`:

```
<a onclick="closePopup();return false;">close</a>
```

Comment: I changed the line but that did not solve it.. vaque enough so I copied your jsfiddle and pasted it. after refreshing with the jsfiddle code it worked! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like this

```
pd.style.display="hidden"
```

I think their are issues about .display="none"

Comment: Not working, even the pop-up alert is not being displayed.. also tried your code "hidden" and 'hidden'